# Duplicate element in a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops

I am trying to write code that can detect which element in a function is repeated and how many times it is repeated. The code will also ignore the differences in casing.

example: Example
"abcde" -> 0 # no characters repeats more than once
"aabbcde" -> 2 # 'a' and 'b'
"aabBcde" -> 2 # 'a' occurs twice and 'b' twice (`b` and `B`)
"indivisibility" -> 1 # 'i' occurs six times

Here is my code:

```
    //...
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j <str.length; j++){
          if(str[i] === str[j]){
            count = count + 1 //Count will tally how many times each given letter is repeated
            return console.log(`${str[i]} occurs ${count}`)
          }
      }
      
    }
  }
  duplicateCount('blaaaab');
```

Comment: I recommend learning more about "hash map" or "dictionary" data structure in JavaScript as one way to solve this.

Comment: If your string contains only letters from a-z, I would use an array of size 26 and store each character count based on its ASCII value. Time Complexity will be O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the string and store the # of occurrences of the character

```js
function duplicateCount(str) {
   let result = {}
   for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
       const char = str[i]
       if(char in result) {
           result[char] +=1
       } else {
           result[char] = 1
       }
   }
   return result
}
        
console.log(duplicateCount('blaaaab'));
```

#### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in - for..in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in - in operator
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp - Javascript Object

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner at JS and this really made sense. I havent seen the If statement that you wrote written in this way. Can you explain it to me? Is it a special kind of if statement? Similar to the "for in" and "for of" loops? What is it called? Can you also explain the syntax of this "let result = {}"?

Comment: It just checks to see if the object **result** has the property. So on the first loop, the if..else statement translates to `if the object **result** has the property named 'a', increment the counter by one, if not, create the property 'a' and give it the value 1` [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [this explains what the in operator is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Answer (score 0):

```
function repeatedCharacters(str){
   try{ 
return str.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").match(/(.)\1+/g).length;
 }
 catch(e){ 
return 0;
 } // if TypeError
}
console.log(repeatedCharacters("CheeecKKCaaz"))
```

The above code tells about how many characters are repeated , you can modify it to determine the occurrence of each character.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Set` structure here and get result with O(n)

```
const word = "abcdEedutyhaaaa";

const duplicates = Array.from(word.toLowerCase())
  .reduce((builder, char) => {
    builder.all.has(char) ? builder.duplicate.add(char) : builder.all.add(char);
    return builder;
  }, { duplicate: new Set(), all: new Set() })
  .duplicate
  .size;

console.log(duplicates); // => 3
```